# how to use a class with generics without having to declare the generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

First of all, I am coming from Java background so please forgive me for my mistakes:

This is my class

```
 class ParameterHandler<T>
 {

        public static Dictionary<string, Converter<T>> parameters = 
               new Dictionary<string, Converter<T>>();

        public static void addParameter(string parameterName, Converter<T> converter){
            parameters.Add(parameterName, converter);
        }

        static T getValue(string parameterName, string stringValue){
            return parameters[parameterName].getValue(stringValue);
        }
 }
```

and this is my `Converter` interface

```
interface Converter <T>
{
        T getValue(string stringValue);
}
```

I wonder if I can use the parameterhandler without having to declare `T` as a generic type for it

I just need to do something like

```
ParameterHandler.addParameter("some", Some Implementation for Converter)
```

and to put you in the whole picture, this is one of my implementation for the `Converter`

```
class IntConverter : Converter<int>
{
        int getValue(string stringValue)
        {
            return int.Parse(stringValue);
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to have different types of converters in the dictionary `paramateres`?

Comment: @TaherRahgooy yes and I also have this  `public static Dictionary<string, Converter<T>> parameters = new Dictionary<string, Converter<T>>();` so the function `addParameter` will just add a new entry in this dictionary. u got me pllease?

Comment: What is the key being used for? Is it just storing a type name, or will you potentially have multiple converters for each `T`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must define an interface that is base for all converters:

```
 interface Converter
 {
 }
 interface Converter<T> : Converter
 {
     T getValue(string stringValue);
 }
```

Then:

```
class ParameterHandler
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Converter> parameters = 
           new Dictionary<string, Converter>();

    public static void addParameter<T>(string parameterName, Converter<T> converter){
        parameters.Add(parameterName, converter);
    }

    static T getValue<T>(string parameterName, string stringValue){
        if(!parameters[parameterName] is Convereter<T>)
             throw new Exception("Invalid Type");

        return ((Convereter<T>)parameters[parameterName]).getValue(stringValue);
    }
}
```

Note that, in your initial model, you have a different dictionary for each type `T`, `Converter<int>.parameters` and `Converter<double>.parameters` are not the same.

Comment: this is not safe, i can't pass `object` to my dictionary

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, Yes, but in your model the dictionary can contain just the one type for each `T`.

Comment: how can I use the getValue then ? i can't do something like this: `ParameterHandler.getValue(key, value)`

Comment: `ParameterHandler.getValue<int>(key, value)`, or making the `getValue` return type as object.

Comment: i don't know the type in the runtime, it is okay it seems we are guessing here, thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can create a non-generic ParameterHandler class with a generic `addParameter` method:

```
public static class ParameterHandler
{
    public static void addParameter<T>(string name, Converter<T> c)
    {
        ParameterHandler<T>.addParameter(name, c);
    }
}
```

then you can use

```
ParameterHandler.addParameter("some", new IntConverter());
```

Comment: in that case, i would like to tell u more, i have this dictionary public static `Dictionary<string, Converter<T>> parameters = new Dictionary<string, Converter<T>>();`
what would i pass instead of `T`  please?

Comment: could you help pleaes?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: Where is that defined? In this case `T` is `int`. If you want to declare it in a non-generic type then you'll need to use `object` for `T` and wrap your individual `Converter<T>` instances in a class implementing `Converter<object>`. Alternatively you could add a non-generic `Converter` interface with a `object getValue(string stringValue);` method.